# Client asks for SSN in Statement of Work and wants it sent signed via email

Tags: email, contracting, security

In a Statement of Work from a client, there's a field for the Social Security Number or the Tax Identification Number in the *Contractor* details. The client wants this SoW sent back signed, over email, which is an insecure medium, so that that budget would be approved for the contract.

Is this request customary? What should a contractor do in this situation?

Comment: Encrypt the file, and provide the password by phone.

Comment: Nope, the only time I've ever given out my SSN is on mandatory government tax forms like a W9 (for the United States).  I wouldn't trust them to have the unencrypted email in their HR (or whatever) department once I provided the password either.  A phone call asking why they need my SSN would be my next step.

Comment: @AndrewBartel: they want the SSN so they can pay the contractor.

Comment: Yep. Employment, and the taxes associated with it, would be one of the legitimate uses of ssn.

Comment: I have never seen an SoW require the SSN though. That is usually dealt with in a separate document.

Comment: yeah... so they need it because when they pay you they also declare it. I would explain my concerns and would figure out a secure way of giving them the form.

Comment: Assuming this is the US, the standard practice is a particular form called a W9, I assumed they wanted it for something else since they didn't give you that.  But if it's about taxes, on either end, they should be using that, I'm a little confused why they aren't.

Comment: Would you expect a hard copy to be more secure? I've worked places where documents with SSN were left laying out where *customers* could reach/read them. To me, it doesn't matter how I provide my SSN: Once I give it away its security is out of my hands. I rely on credit/identity monitoring, and not security practices (or lack thereof) I can't control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reply that you will submit a W9 form (by fax or regular mail) after the contract is signed.

If you are a company, you should also have a EIN/TIN which is not your SSN and you can supply that one, as those are difficult to use for identity theft purposes.

Comment: Indeed, later I was asked to fill in a W9 anyway.